# Is it possible to reduce the size of the simplest Android app?

Tags: android

When I create a project and export it right away without any modifications, the size of the app would be around 700 kb. I don't think the size of an app that displays just some text should be that high. I've seen apps that are around 10 kb that do the same and that seems reasonable. I need to know why the ADT is designed to include a lot of unnecessary stuff in the APK file that makes the size of the app so high. 
I know about tools like proguard  and so on that reduce the size of the application but I just need to reduce the size of the apps and let it not be any more than the size it actually needs to be.
Is it a flaw of the ADT?

(Of course, I have it all updated and I use Ubuntu, if that matters. )
Thank you.

Comment: Well, what is the size of the app when you enable proguard and make a signed APK? The app that you're looking at that's 10 KB most likely a signed APK proguard enabled.  Without it, the dependencies you include will be there in full whether you use it or not.

Comment: i think it all depends up on resources,library,dependency you are using in your project..I mean removing all above think will reduce size...but after that your app will be just a showcase display single screen (useless)...

Answer (score 4):

> I need to know why the ADT is designed to include a lot of unnecessary stuff in the APK file that makes the size of the app so high.

Support for Eclipse+ADT ended about five months ago. Complaining about discontinued tools is pointless.

Since you decided not to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I am going to guess that your problem comes from `appcompat-v7`. I just created two projects in Android Studio, one using the "Blank Activity" template and relying on `appcompat-v7` and `design` (~1.4MB) and one using the "Empty Activity" template and where I removed `appcompat-v7` (~30KB).

You may feel that `appcompat-v7` is "unnecessary". I tend to agree. Google disagrees. Google created Android Studio (and the deprecated ADT Plugin for Eclipse); you and I did not. Google is welcome to have its new-project and new-activity templates rely upon `appcompat-v7`. You do not have to use the new-activity template, and you can remove `appcompat-v7` from the `build.gradle` file of your project.

Or, you are welcome to create your own IDE and convince developers to use it.

> Is it a flaw of the ADT?

No. It is an implementation decision.

Answer (score 0):

Check, what you are import to your application.
`build.gradle`.

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`

More information look at this information about libraries.

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

Comment: I don't understand how that would help reduce the size of the app.

Comment: the question is about size not dependencies..as much i can see OP said size is 700kb or sort so OP is using Eclipse not Android Studio (and in Studio a simple app would size 1-1.5 Mb)..

Answer (score 0):

First of all : Make sure to remove all libraries in your `build.gradle` wich you do not need.
Second of all : if you are using Google play services just for google maps make sure to compile this : `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'`instead of this : `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`.
Third of all : if you are using .jpg files, i would recommand to compresse it as much as possible.

Comment: the question is about size not dependencies..as much i can see OP said size is 700kb or sort so OP is using Eclipse not Android Studio (and in Studio a simple app would size 1-1.5 Mb)..

Comment: i don't know what to do in eclipse but i recommend if you are using .jpg files to compress it as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a flaw - it is a compromise. As an example for a small app you can look into FAST / FASTER ( down to ~64kb ) - https://github.com/ligi/FAST
Check if you are using appcompat or google-play and if you can remove it as one aspect to make it smaller. Every dependency adds to your size

Comment: Hi, could you tell me where the src files are in that repo? I tried searching for the code and I couldn't find any. Am I missing something?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I opened the project in android studio and it grayed the src file out. :)