# How to reduce apk size?

Tags: android, android-studio

Why even a "Hello World" project is so huge.Why may such a simple project weigh one, or more MB? And how to solve it?
ProGuard can shrink a huge code, but, when the project is so tiny, how to fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37255265/115145

Comment: @Filip Rosca you have to remove your ic-launcher from drawable or mimpmap directory and mostly app size increase because of multiple images in drawable directory .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to reduce the size of the simplest Android app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254963/is-it-possible-to-reduce-the-size-of-the-simplest-android-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to shrink your APK (this is in your module's build.gradle file):

...

```
android {

  ...

  buildTypes {
      release {
          minifyEnabled true
          shrinkResources true
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
   }

...

}
```